# Drupal : call drupal_get_form from AJAX

Tags: ajax, drupal, forms

I'd like to call a form that is created in the .module file. It means that in a AJAX function located in a HTML page of drupal, I'd like to append a form that is defined in the module file with a DIV presents in my HTML file.

Do you have a solution to have only the code HTML generated by drupal for a form? But the call to Drupal would be in an AJAX Function.

Actually, I can create a path '?myProject/form' where the form is generated. However, I cannot append the full content of the html page (header, footer of drupal). I only want to append the HTML code of the form.

I hope that I'm understandable

Thank you very much

Bat

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have a 'page callback' with a function like this in your hook_menu:

```
$items['myProject/form/%'] = array(
  'title' => t('Get a form'),
  'description' => 'Get form',
  'access callback' => 'user_access',
  'page callback' => '_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array(2),
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

And maybe you have this function defined:

```
function _get_form($form_id){
   return "Hello World with " . $form_id; //returns the whole page with this text
}
```

If you change `return` for `print`, Drupal only return this text, like this:

```
function _get_form($form_id){
   print "Hello World with " . $form_id; //returns only this text
}
```

I hope it helps